# How to format the final results digit of the calculations in Objective-C?

Tags: objective-c

I have this code:

```
double s = [year.text doubleValue]*31536000;
second.text=[[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"%2g", s];
```

When I try to calculate the final result is `3.1536e+07`

How do I make the result `31536000` without `e+07`?

Comment: Actually, why not use `... initWithFormat:@"%f", s];`?

Answer (score 2):

The `%g` and `%G` conversions print the argument in the style of `%e` or `%E` (respectively) if the exponent would be less than -4 or greater than or equal to the precision; otherwise they use the `%f` style.
You should use `%f`.

```
double s = [year.text doubleValue]*31536000;
second.text=[[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"%f", s];
```

Answer (score 0):

Simple use %f.

```
NSString *str = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"%f", s];
second.text = str;
```

The `second` may result the string without the "e+07"

The `f` is because we're working w/ [floating point numbers](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floating_point).

Comment: `e`, `f`, `g` are all format string for floating point numbers, with some differences in them.

Answer (score 0):

You should try:

```
double s = [year.text doubleValue]*31536000;
second.text=[[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"%lf", s];
```